PyInstaller on macOS: IndexError 'tuple index out of range' when including .app folder in datas
I'm encountering an issue with PyInstaller when building my Python application on macOS. I keep getting the following error:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
...
File ".../PyInstaller/utils/osx.py", line 672, in collect_files_from_framework_bundles
  dir_name = remaining_path_parts[2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Context:

Operating System: macOS on Mac mini M2 (Apple Silicon)
Python Versions Tried: 3.8, 3.9, and 3.12
PyInstaller Versions Tried: 6.10.0 and 6.11.0
Goal: Build a Python application into a macOS executable, including specific resources like the Chromium browser and chromedriver for macOS (Intel and ARM).

Folder Structure:
Here’s the relevant folder structure:
project_dir/
├── app_src/
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── assets/
│   ├── drivers/
│   │   ├── chromium/
│   │   │   └── macos/
│   │   │       ├── mac/            # Contains Chromium.app (Intel)
│   │   │       │   └── Chromium.app
│   │   │       └── mac_arm/        # Contains Chromium.app (ARM)
│   │   │           └── Chromium.app
│   │   └── chromedriver/
│   │       └── macos/
│   │           ├── mac/
│   │           │   └── chromedriver
│   │           └── mac_arm/
│   │               └── chromedriver
├── core_extensions/
│   ├── ...
├── final_output/
│   └── macos/
│       ├── build/
│       └── dist/
└── pyinstaller.spec

Content of the pyinstaller.spec file:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import shutil

block_cipher = None
project_dir = os.getcwd()

dist_dir = os.path.join(project_dir, 'final_output', 'macos', 'dist')

if os.path.exists(dist_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(dist_dir)

datas = [
    # Assets
    (os.path.join(project_dir, 'app_src', 'assets'), 'assets'),

    # Core Extensions
    (os.path.join(project_dir, 'core_extensions'), 'core_extensions'),

    # Chromium for macOS
    (os.path.join(project_dir, 'app_src', 'drivers', 'chromium', 'macos', 'mac'), 'drivers/chromium/macos/mac'),
    (os.path.join(project_dir, 'app_src', 'drivers', 'chromium', 'macos', 'mac_arm'), 'drivers/chromium/macos/mac_arm'),

    # Chromedriver for macOS
    (os.path.join(project_dir, 'app_src', 'drivers', 'chromedriver', 'macos', 'mac', 'chromedriver'), 'drivers/chromedriver/macos/mac'),
    (os.path.join(project_dir, 'app_src', 'drivers', 'chromedriver', 'macos', 'mac_arm', 'chromedriver'), 'drivers/chromedriver/macos/mac_arm')
]

a = Analysis(
    [os.path.join(project_dir, 'app_src', 'main.py')],
    binaries=[],
    datas=datas,
    excludes=[],
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    cipher=block_cipher,
    hiddenimports=['_cffi_backend'],
    pathex=[os.path.join(project_dir, 'app_src')]
)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    upx=True,
    debug=False,
    strip=False,
    name='example',
    console=False,
    exclude_binaries=True,
    bundle_identifier='com.yourcompany.example'
)

coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    upx=True,
    strip=False,
    name='example'
)

Command Used:
pyinstaller ./final_output/macos/build/pyinstaller.spec --distpath ./final_output/macos --workpath ./final_output/macos/build

Full Error:
...
9846 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/example/desktop_app/app_src/.venv/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(_console_script_run())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/example/desktop_app/app_src/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 231, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/example/desktop_app/app_src/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 215, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/example/desktop_app/app_src/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 70, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/example/desktop_app/app_src/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1227, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/example/desktop_app/app_src/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1167, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "./final_output/macos/build/pyinstaller.spec", line 28, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/example/desktop_app/app_src/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/example/desktop_app/app_src/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/example/desktop_app/app_src/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 971, in assemble
    combined_toc += osxutils.collect_files_from_framework_bundles(combined_toc)
  File "/Users/administrator/Desktop/example/desktop_app/app_src/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/osx.py", line 672, in collect_files_from_framework_bundles
    dir_name = remaining_path_parts[2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Steps Tried So Far:

Changing Python Versions: I tried Python 3.8, 3.9, and 3.12, all resulting in the same error.

Switching PyInstaller Versions: Tried with PyInstaller 6.10.0 and 6.11.0, both without success.

Renaming Chromium.app: I renamed Chromium.app to Chromium to prevent PyInstaller from treating it as a macOS bundle, then updated all references in .spec and code. The error still occurs.

Disabling UPX: Set upx=False in the .spec file. No effect.

Using Tree from PyInstaller: Tried importing and using Tree to add the Chromium.app folder:
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import Tree

This resulted in an error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Tree' from 'PyInstaller.utils.hooks'


Custom Function to Collect Files: I used a custom function to recursively add files from Chromium.app:
def collect_app_files(source_dir, target_dir):
    files = []
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source_dir):
        for filename in filenames:
            file_source = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_target = os.path.join(target_dir, os.path.relpath(root, source_dir))
            files.append((file_source, file_target))
    return files

Unfortunately, this did not fix the issue either.

Debug Logging: Ran PyInstaller with --log-level=DEBUG for more insights, but no additional clues surfaced.


Additional Information:

Hardware: Mac mini M2 (Apple Silicon)
Objective: Include the Chromium browser (both Intel and ARM versions) in the final macOS application build.

Questions:

How can I resolve this IndexError: tuple index out of range when building with PyInstaller on macOS?
Has anyone encountered and solved a similar issue?

Thank you for your help in advance !
